# Tornado read until close method error

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, tcpserver

I am trying to create TCP server in python with a tornado.
My handle stream method looks like this,

```
async def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
    while True:
        try:
            stream.read_until_close(streaming_callback=self._on_read)
        except StreamClosedError:
            break
```

in the `_on_read` method, I am trying to read and process the data but whenever a new client connects to the server it gives `AssertionError: Already reading` error.

```
 File "/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 525, in read_until_close
    future = self._set_read_callback(callback)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 860, in _set_read_callback
    assert self._read_future is None, "Already reading"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[read_until_close](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/iostream.html?#tornado.iostream.BaseIOStream.read_until_close) asynchronously reads all data from the socket until it is closed. `read_until_close` has to be called once but the cycle forces the second call that's why you got an error:

- on the first iteration, `read_until_close` sets `streaming_callback` and returns `Future` so that you could await it or use later;
- on the second iteration, `read_until_close` raises an exception since you already set a callback on the first iteration.

`read_until_close` returns `Future` object and you can `await` it to make things work:

```
async def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
    try:
        await stream.read_until_close(streaming_callback=self._on_read)
    except StreamClosedError:
        # do something
```